# Which library contains FSEventsGetCurrentEventId?

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I was trying to find the function `FSEventsGetCurrentEventId` so I can use it in my ctypes program.

I thought it was in this lib: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/CarbonCore`

However I can't find it. Does anyone know which library its in? Thanks

Comment: How are you determining that it's not in that library? Because it is on my 10.9.5 system. `nm -mg /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/CarbonCore | grep FSEventsGetCurrentEventId` -> `000000000002fde1 (__TEXT,__text) external _FSEventsGetCurrentEventId`.

Comment: Thanks Ken I was opening that library with `ctypes.open` and then declaring the function and it would throw `symbol not found`. I found the right path it was `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents` does that look right? thanks ken!

Comment: If you find the symbol there, then it's right.  My system doesn't have that library, but that may be a different between OS versions.

Comment: Oh crap thanks for that note on your system can you please tell me what library this is in on your system, because im trying to create this for all systems. My system is 10.10.1. For you is it in `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/CarbonCore`? What's your system? Thakns very much!

Comment: Look at my first comment.

Comment: @KenThomases Ah totally missed that my head was deep in some code at the time haha thanks for that! I'll test it on 10.9 and report back if the results match. :)